# Flex 4: 1120: Access of undefined property

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, undefined

New to Flex and I am trying to work the the ArrayCollection class and I keep getting:
1120: Access of undefined property

Something like:

```
var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var item:Object = new Object();

list.addItem( item );
```

> 1120: Access of undefined property
>   list

Isn't the array list being defined in the first line?

Updated: 03-11
Here is my full mxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application name="Spark_List_dataProvider_XML_test"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            var item:Object = new Object();

            list.addItem( item );

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Yes, this code snippet should work. I'm unclear why it doesn't based on your code snippet.  Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Agree with @AlucinariOlim & @Flextras that you haven't provided enough information to solve the problem. The error lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Your code isn't showing correctly, but it already looks like you are trying to invoke functions/methods directly in the Script block.  The Script block is only allowed to have function declarations.  To get your code to work you need to execute the "list.addItem(item);" in a function that is invoked in an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

That code works just fine.  It appears as though:

1) something might be using your ArrayCollection as a dataProvider, and wants a property on the items that isn't there
2) you have a function that is looking for a property on the items that you are adding, and the property isn't there

Please post something closer to your real code, your error dump, and/or what is referencing the ArrayCollection for additional help.

Check the error dump for the class and line number that is producing the error and look there for what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                var lista:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                var item:Object = new Object();

                lista.addItem(item);

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```